# Displaying automatically generated SQL code from column sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I would want to be able to display those automatically generated SQL code on the database web page, when doing a primary sorting on a specific column in web grid.

For Instance, if you click on any column header on a database web page, the selected column will be sorted as a primary sorting column and then display the result in ascending or descending order.

My question is, would it be possible to retrieve those automatically generated SQL code behind the sorting process and display them onto the web page ? can't seems too find any resource about this. Any reading that can be used as a reference will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it by using `Context Log property`.

```
using (var context = new BlogContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 

    // Your code here... 
}
```

You can use it for Logging to different places.Such as  `log to memory`,`file` and  by using different kinds of [**TextWriter**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.aspx).

```
public class MyLogger 
{ 
    public void Log(string component, string message) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Component: {0} Message: {1} ", component, message); 
    } 
}

//This could be hooked up to the EF Log property like this:

var logger = new MyLogger(); 
context.Database.Log = s => logger.Log("MyEFApp", s);
```

You can refer this doc for more info : [**Logging and Intercepting Database Operations**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx)

Comment: @phantom When you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for answer. It's not compulsory at all, but it's reasonable and recommended. For more information take a look at this post: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647)

Comment: Thanks mate :) @RezaAghaei

Comment: Nice to see this helped to you :) @phantom